# Get the multiples from a file and copy them on another

Tags: c, file, scanf

My intention is to get all the numbers that exist on the file `multiples.txt` and write the multiples of the desired integer (input by the user).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE *f, *fs;
    int value, multiple, n;

    f = fopen("multiples.txt", "r");

    if (f == NULL)
        printf("Error\n");

    fs = fopen("exit.txt", "w");

    if (fs == NULL)
        printf("Error\n");

    printf("Write a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    do {
        n = fscanf(f, "%d", multiple);

        if (multiple % value == 0) {
            fprintf(fs, "%d", multiple);
        }

    } while (n != EOF);

    fclose(f);
    fclose(fs);
}
```

My program crashes and I can't figure where it comes from.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume the original [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag was actually correct, and give an answer that (I think) makes better use of the capabilities of C++ instead of just C.

Since we want to copy items that meet a particular criterion, we can use the `std::copy_if` algorithm to handle the majority of the work. We also need to specify the "rule" for what items to copy. We typically want to use streams instead of C-style `FILE *`s, especially since the latter don't support iterators.

Taking those ideas into account, we'd write the code more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("multiples.txt");
    std::ofstream out("exit.txt");

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::istream_iterator<int> begin(in), end;

    std::copy_if(begin, end,
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(out),
        [n](int i) { return i % n == 0; });
}
```

As you can see, this eliminates the opportunity for the error that originally prompted the question (along with the error you had in dealing with the end of file incorrectly).

If you are going to do the job in C, you usually want to combine reading input with testing whether the input succeeded to get a loop that reads to the end of a file, then stops at the right time. In this case you're reading with `fscanf`, so one fairly easy way to write the loop correctly would look something like:

```
while (1 == fscanf(f, "%d", &multiple))
    if (multiple % value == 0)
        fprintf(fs, "%d", multiple);
```

The return value from `fscanf` is the number of "items" successfully converted. Here we're asking for one integer to be read/converted, and then testing whether that happened.

One minor addition (that applies to both): I've written the code above to match that in the question in one respect: it writes out the resulting numbers without any delimiter between them. For example, if you had an input containing `2 4 5 8` and the user entered `2`, it would produce output of `248`, so in the result you wouldn't be able to tell which digits came from which inputs. In real use, you almost certainly want to separate them with something (commas, spaces, new-lines, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you just enable warnings (`-Wall` for starters), the compiler *just tells you*:

```
test.cpp:20:29: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        n = fscanf(f, "%d", multiple);
                       ~~   ^~~~~~~~
```

You forgot to take the address of `multiple`

> **Always** use the tools to spot your errors

There are many other issues that can be solved with a trip to the documentation (e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Answer (score 0):

```
n=fscanf(f, "%d", multiple);
```

I thinks this point has a little problem

```
n=fscanf(f, "%d", &multiple);
```

add "&"

Comment: also, fscanf does not return EOF on end of file. It returns the number of matched elements.

Comment: I thinks fscanf returns the number of you get.

I recommend you
while( fscanf(f, "%d", &multiple) == 1 ) {
   //what you want.
}

:)

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/?kw=fscanf and return value parts

Comment: or there are charaters in multiples.txt, you need to use fgets and check it is a number or not.

Comment: but why ==1? that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: if fscanf reads a number correctly in your case, then return 1. or if fscanf cannot read correctly because of character or EOF, then it returns 0.
-----
case 1: fscanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
In case1, fscanf can return 0, 1, 2.
-----
in cplusplus.com said
"This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure"